# Can I force Mathematica to use machine precision?

Tags: machine-precision

Some built-in functions (like `Exp`) give an arbitrary precision result, even when the argument is a machine precision number. Example:

```
Exp[-10.] // Precision
```

> MachinePrecision

```
Exp[-1000.] // Precision
```

> 12.9546

I can of course `Clip` and `Chop` the result to a machine precision number, but I would like to avoid the cost of arbitrary precision calculations (and unpacking, if the argument is a packed array) in the first place. For example here:

```
x = Range[-10.^6, 10.^6];
Timing[y = Exp[-x^2/2];]
PackedArrayQ[y]
```

The calculation takes 7s on my PC (machine precision calculation would take ~0.1s) and the result isn't a packed array.

Comment: The only thing I can think of at the moment is `Compile`, is it of interest?

Comment: Thanks @OleksandrR., `System`SetSystemOptions["CatchMachineUnderflow" -> False];` works perfectly. I did look for similar questions, but didn't find the one you linked. It's obviously a duplicate. Should delete it myself or vote to close?

Comment: We may as well VTC so that this can serve as another pointer to help other people search in the future. As @xzczd says, `Compile` can also work, and if you don't feel like setting a global option, the `Compile` option `"RuntimeOptions" -> {"CatchMachineUnderflow" -> False}` could be a good alternative.