# Plot3D discrepancy between MMA 10 and 11.3 - possible small numbers issue

Tags: plotting, machine-precision, arbitrary-precision

I'm having some troubles with the following code I wrote in MMA 10 some time ago:

```
Clear[g, a, b, c, amp]

g[x_] := I (2 Sqrt[E])/(Pi*b) Exp[-(x - c/2)^2/(2 b^2)] Exp[I (2 Pi)/a (x)] (x - c/2);

amp[x_, k_] = Integrate[-I*g[xd] Exp[-I k xd ], {xd, 0, x}];

Plot3D[
 Abs[5 amp[x, k*50 + shift] /. {a -> 0.01, c -> 1, b -> 1/8, 
    shift -> 2 Pi/0.01}],
 {x, 0, 1}, {k, -1, 1},
 PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {-1, 1}, {0, 1}},
 LabelStyle -> {24, Black},
 BoxStyle -> Black,
 TicksStyle -> Black,
 PlotPoints -> 50,
 ImageSize -> 500]
```

The output in MMA 10 looks like the following plot:

[image]

However, in MMA 11.3 I get this error message and this output plot:

> General::munfl: Exp[-5704.68-289.16 I] is too small to represent as a normalized machine number; precision may be lost.
>
> General::munfl: Exp[-5704.68-289.16 I] is too small to represent as a normalized machine number; precision may be lost.
>
> [image]

It looks like a precision problem, but setting WorkingPrecision to different values doesn't help. I'm sure I've read something about it on stackexchange, but I can't remember where (it might be something related to the fact that MMA 11.3 doesn't work with arbitrary precision automatically, but I might be talking nonsense...)

Comment: Hm. I also observed that Mathematica 11.3 throws `General::munfl`much more often than the version before...

Comment: I found something related in https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/170416/new-generalmunfl-error-and-loss-of-precision : the answers are a bit annoying though, it looks like there is no way of having old codes working again without rewriting parts of them

Comment: `WorkingPrecision` will work if you replace the `0.01` with exact versions.

Comment: @BrettChampion I tried WorkingPrecision->Infinity using 1/100 instead of 0.01 but it still doesn't work. It works with WorkingPrecision->50, 20, 10 and 5 (which confuses me a bit...)  Also, this is a toy case, while in a realistic code I would have very weird numbers for a,b,c (e.g one value could be 0.00004622): how do I replace them with the corresponding exact version?

Comment: You can't use Infinity for the working precision. For your weird numbers, just use Rationalize before plotting, e.g., `Plot3D[Evaluate[Rationalize[.., 0]], ..]`

Answer (score 4):

[Turning](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1244/posting-answers-in-comments) a combination of great comments into an answer. The cause is Mathematica [no longer checking for underflow](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/180865/2036) since 11.3. Workaround is to turn your function description to a numerically exact form using `Rationalize` and making `Plot3D` to use arbitrary precision (which is no-longer the default behaviour) by explicitly setting `WorkingPrecision -> 5`.

```
rr = Rationalize[
  Abs[5 amp[x, k*50 + shift] /. {a -> 0.01, c -> 1, b -> 1/8, 
     shift -> 2 Pi/0.01}], 0];
Plot3D[rr, {x, 0, 1}, {k, -1, 1}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {-1, 1}, {0, 1}}, LabelStyle -> {24, Black}, 
 BoxStyle -> Black, TicksStyle -> Black, PlotPoints -> 50, 
 ImageSize -> 500, WorkingPrecision -> 5]
```

[image]

If I do not `Rationalize` before hand it gives a warning, but still calculates using `WorkingPrecision`. However, without `Rationalize` it seems to require larger `WorkinPrecision` for a reasonable result. I have an example, where even `WorkingPrecision->1000` does not give the same plot, as I get with `v11.1`. If someone can explain it, I am happy to extend the answer.

I would also expect

```
rr = N[Abs[
   5 amp[x, k*50 + shift] /. {a -> 0.01, c -> 1, b -> 1/8, 
     shift -> 2 Pi/0.01}], 25]
Plot3D[rr, {x, 0, 1}, {k, -1, 1}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {-1, 1}, {0, 1}}, LabelStyle -> {24, Black}, 
 BoxStyle -> Black, TicksStyle -> Black, PlotPoints -> 50, 
 ImageSize -> 500]
```

to work, but it does not. It really seems, that **`WorkingPrecision` and `Rationalize`** are required.

Comment: `N[1.0*Pi, 200]` and `N[1.0*Pi]` give the same result, because the machine precision 1.0 "infects" the calculation.  (Even though machine precision is ~16 digits, it's considered to be lower precision than any arbitrary precision.)  So `N` by itself isn't enough to define `rr`.  `SetPrecision`, on the other hand, can forcibly increase the precision.  Even in that case, though, you still need to use `WorkingPrecision` for the plot, since it determines the precision of the specific values of `x` and `k` used to evaluate `rr`. Otherwise the default is to use machine precision and it underflows.