# Set Underflow precision in Mathematica 12 same as version 11.x

Tags: equation-solving, machine-precision, arbitrary-precision, precision-and-accuracy

It seems like Mathematica version 12 sets arbitrary underflow precision depending on the function, but I would like the underflow precision to be same as what was for previous version of Mathematica as it was giving me correct results. Is there any command to globally set the underflow precision to the same as it was in previous versions?

Comment: See also [(170416)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/170416). Overall, there are quite many posts related exactly to this issue.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I don't know how to correct the arbitrary underflow precision to what it was earlier. Thanks for the link but the link you suggested doesn't give a solution to the problem.

Comment: @m_goldberg I still don't understand should I modify Exp[x] or what exactly needs to be done?